# Java Ucanaccess Insert data into the table ignoring duplicate records (primary key)

Tags: java, ucanaccess

Good afternoon people,
I'm trying to insert some data into the access table but it doesn't run due to a primary key violation

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException;

public class teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try
        {
            String Query = "INSERT INTO 005_DADOS_HISTORICOS ( DT_ARQUIVO, UF_LIC, CHASSI, NM_FILE, DT_EXEC_ROBO, TEMPO_DECORRIDO, RESULTADO_FINAL ) SELECT DT_ARQUIVO, UF_LIC, CHASSI, NM_FILE, DT_EXEC_ROBO, TEMPO_DECORRIDO, RTrim(LTrim(Replace(Replace([RESULTADO_ROBO],\"*\",\"\"),\"=\",\"\"))) FROM 003_DADOS_TRATATIVA;";
            baseDados.updateAccess("C://BOT_REENVIO_DETRAN//database.accdb", Query);
            System.out.println("Dados Inseridos");
        }       
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Error:

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10577 table: Z_005_DADOS_HISTORICOS
```

How do I insert exclusive records and simply ignore duplicate records?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an existing entry to the database and that cannot work because a column in your table is unique, which means that you cannot add duplicate entries.

You cannot ignore the duplicate entries.
So you have to change your table definition

please check this [unique sql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Class `UcanaccessSQLException` extends class `java.sql.SQLException` which contains a *reason* and a *vendor code* and a *message*. If you want to ignore attempts to insert a duplicate row into a table, then in your `catch` block check the *message*. If it is *integrity constraint violation* just ignore. If it is not, handle appropriately as per your requirements.